# how do I enable collisions between a rigid body and cloth without affecting the rigid body simulation

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation, collision

I have a nice rigid-body simulation that needs to collide with a cloth sim but I can't find a way of getting the cloth to collide with the actual position of the rigid body. when the cloth sim runs, it only collides with the original position of the rigid body. I don't want the cloth sim to affect the rigid body sim. What can I do?

Comment: Well, cloth and rigid body simulation do not interact with each other. They work differently and cannot be mixed. If you want the cloth to take the moving rigid body into account, you have to bake the rigid body simulation to keyframes. But of course you cannot change the simulation afterwards anymore.